# windows mobile corrupt filesystem

Tags: filesystems, windows-mobile, corrupt, activesync

I have some issues on a WM 6.5 device that the flashdisk gets corrupt once a while.
At this moment I have contact with the distributor about it, but maybe someone can help me with a good "checkdisk" tool that i can use the check flashdrive of the WM 6.5 device.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the [Object Store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885891.aspx), RAM drive, or SD Card that's getting corrupted?
How is this drive formatted? FAT? TFAT?

How do you know it's corrupted? What are the symptoms?

To answer your question, you may be able to use the [ScanDrive()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms891845.aspx) function, though that may require the partition to be unmounted. (i.e. you may not be able to use it on the ObjectStore)

Flash memory by its nature only lasts for a number of write cycles before the cells go bad. If you have a database, or other frequently used file, you may have worn out the memory cells.

NAND flash memory can only be read from a certain number of times before going bad. So, if you have a particular file that is read frequently enough you may need to erase it and re-write occasionally. See [Read Disturb](http://www.broadbandreports.com/r0/download/1507743~59e7b9dda2c0e0a0f7ff119a7611c641/flash_mem_summit_jcooke_inconvenient_truths_nand.pdf).